# How to make a call with voice in Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, voice-recording

I'm building an application which can recording the incoming call. I want the incoming call have some voice to test my app. How to config Emulator to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dummy calls from your emulator from `DDMS -> Emulator Control`

DDMS can be added from the right top button near to "`Java`" button